# <video> autoplay on chrome android interrupts Spotify

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, video

I work for a company that is currently setting up video advertising on mobile and for this we need the HTML5 `<video>` element. Now that Chrome 53 is out and it supports muted autoplay we had great hopes for our new video advertisement.

Unfortunately we get complains from clients that even muted video autoplay interrupts Spotify (and other background media playback).

Is there a way around this? Our `<video>` element looks like this:

```
<video width="320" height="180" preload="auto" muted="" autoplay="" webkit-playsinline="" ><source src="....." type="video/mp4"></video>
```

I already tried setting volume to 0 from javascript, but this doesn't seem to do anything when muted. (Which makes sense).

We only want to autoplay muted video while keeping background playback enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a current bug in chromium (actively being worked on) that a video with an audio track, but still muted, initiates a MediaSession.

A workaround until we fix that bug would be to use media with no audio tracks and it should prevent this situation.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the bugreport in chromium?

Answer (score 0):

try to do `videoElement.muted=true` it might fix it like in latest chrome 64 which introduce that issue again.

reference: [Chrome 64 Mobile Android not preload and not autoplay muted videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492314/chrome-64-mobile-android-not-preload-and-not-autoplay-muted-videos/48534637)