# Chrome 64 Mobile Android not preload and not autoplay muted videos

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video, autoplay

We encounter issue with Chrome 64 video element which **not loaded** and **not autoplay** although we used video attributes `preload="auto"` and `muted` on HTML element.

the video start load and **paused**, after research, we discovered it never starts to play, like the browser blocked it from playing.

our video doesn't have sound, no sound channel at all, and still no autoplay.

Chrome 63 working great and the same device with 64 stop autoplay.

we did all the things Google Chrome wrote in the release notes, but we think there is another issue we don't know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We discover that you need to add `preload="auto"` as **HTML element attribute**, but you **also must** put on JavaScript HTML element `videoElement.muted=true` as **normal JS attribute**.

it looks like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Is this specific to Android or also on desktop/ios?

Comment: any android, the issue is Chrome 64

Comment: How to add videoElement.muted=true to a video element?

Comment: videoElement.setAttribute('muted','true');

Comment: do so using attribute BUT also using javascript `videoElement.mute = true`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `data-saver` is disabled. If `data-saver` is on, it will not load video.

Comment: we did check it. with Chrome 63 working and with 64 it not when `data-saver` is disabled, in the same device.

Comment: I also tried to reset the chrome and install Chrome 63. it returns to play. installing again Chrome 64 and it stopped. do the fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492315/2542111 and it working!

Comment: How to add videoElement.muted=true ??

Comment: videoElement.setAttribute('muted','true');