# Autoplay is not working in chrome browser on android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, autoplay

I'm developing a web that needs to work on computers, smartphones, and iPhones.
I'm using the `audio` HTML tag with `autoplay` attribute and it doesn't work as expected i.e. *audio does not play automatically*

```
<audio id="audio3" autoplay>
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Is [this any use to you](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 64 Mobile Android not preload and not autoplay muted videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492314/chrome-64-mobile-android-not-preload-and-not-autoplay-muted-videos)

Comment: So why it's working in chrome on computers and not on android devices?

Comment: Did you manage to complete the whole thread provided by RiggsFolly ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the *muted* and *autoplay* attributes together like below

```
<audio id="audio3" autoplay muted>
```

---

Chrome's autoplay policies changed in April 2018, and are as follows

> 1. Muted autoplay is always allowed
> 2. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
>    - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>    - On the desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
>    - On mobile, the user has added the site to his or her home screen.
> 3. Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound

[Refer google docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) for more information

Comment: Also, there is a permissions option in Chrome Browser in Android now that the user can select to allow sounds in autoplay.