# Can anyboy recommend a web based video player that can autoplay video on android mobile platform

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video, autoplay

According to this
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes
Autoplay of video is only possible when they are muted. 
Some  quora questions which I saw were
[Chrome video autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607588/chrome-video-autoplay)
[Chrome 64 Mobile Android not preload and not autoplay muted videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492314/chrome-64-mobile-android-not-preload-and-not-autoplay-muted-videos)
After doing some research I have found that in case of mobile android, for muted videos to autoplay , data saver option in chrome have to be off. 
So does anybody how to autoplay video on mobile android even when
1. Data saver option on chrome is on
2. Video is unmuted
3. User has not interacted with the video

Comment: It has to be impossible I think. Even if there is any way (*a hack*), it has to be closed ASAP

Answer (score 0):

If you developing android app natively you can use [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) for video playback it provides a lot of benefits over default video player in android. This limitation can be easily overcome.

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for the answer but  we are looking for a web based video player, basically to play the video on google chrome browser